# Where to get customized tab bar icons and background?

Tags: iphone, tabbar

Does anyone have a link to resources for customized tabbar controllers for iPhone/iPad development?

Example: Apple's Find my Friends app has some customized tab bar buttons and background. I don't want to design them from scratch.

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The Noun Project](http://thenounproject.com) has a huge collection of icons for almost everything. You can download the icons as SVG files which is a huge plus as you can scale them up to the size of an elephant if you wish to.

**Icons**

- [Glyphish Icon Set](http://www.glyphish.com) (Retina ready, $25, 400 icons. A free version is also available but not retina ready)
- [Tabs Icons](http://www.tabsicons.com/classic/#tabs_free) (Has some free icons, but most of them are paid icon sets)
- [The Working Group Icon Set](http://blog.twg.ca/2010/11/retina-display-icon-set/) (Retina ready, made for UIToolbar, but may also work with a tab bar)
- [Icons Berlin](http://www.iconsberlin.com) (paid icons, €1/icon, they also offer a free tab bar icon online editor if you want to create your own icons)
- [iconfinder.com](http://www.iconfinder.com/search/?q=home) (Icon search engine, licenses may vary)

**Backgrounds / Custom UITabBars**

- [30 free leather textures](http://naldzgraphics.net/freebies/30-free-good-quality-leather-textures/)
- [cocoacontrols](http://www.cocoacontrols.com) (custom UI elements for iOS and Mac OS)
- [Instagram like tabbar](http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/16/raised-center-tab-bar-button/)
- [Pandora UI](http://designmodo.com/pandora-free/)

As I mostly found websites offering paid icons: I'm not affiliated with any of these sites, just added what Google showed me :-)

Comment: Hi Björn, thanks for this list but this is not what I am looking for. To find those Icons is not a problem, but I am interested in the tabbar background file like mentioned in this post: http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/how-to-customize-the-tab-bar-using-ios-5-appearance-api/

Comment: Then you should update your question title, as it also ask for icons ;-) Tabbar backgrounds shouldn't be that hard to find, too. Just search on Google for textures (leather e.g.) and adjust the size of the image. Then you can use the Appearance API of iOS 5 to adjust the background of your UITabBar (just like in the example you posted)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you check out http://www.iconbeast.com

IconBeast Pro now have 1700 iOS Tab Bar and Toolbar icons and most of the icons there are unique.

They also have a set of free icons at http://www.iconbeast.com/free but with much lesser icons and no vector files.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Comment: Is this self-promoted answer? I'm not sure how @AndrewBarber made a judgement...